# Mongodb (mongoose) как изменить значение в массиве обьектов?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "593d0f4c4142fa21d804a717"
},
"date": "неділя, 11 червня 2017 р., 12:37:12",
"client": "Vladimir Ohorenko",
"phone": 935544333,
"email": "expirient@mail.ru",
"order": [
    {
        "date": "неділя, 11 червня 2017 р., 12:37:12",
        "isItDone": false,
        "newprice": 12199,
        "newcount": 1,
        "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit new. Laudantium, culpa.",
        "path": "images/sonyXZ7.png",
        "price": 12199,
        "count": 90,
        "category": "Phones",
        "model": "Xpiria Z7",
        "name": "Sony",
        "_id": "58e5fd76f36d2813f4aa0fb9"
    }
],
"__v": 0
```

}

Есть коллекция, мне нужно изменить значение "isItDone" на "true".. Но не выходить, пишу запрос к базе:

```
Order.update({'order._id': req.body.updatingId},{$set:{'order.isItDone': true}},function(err,data){
        res.send(data);
    });
```

Как правильно обратится к массиву обьекта , и изменить что то в нем? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.getCollection(/* colletion name */).update(
{_id:ObjectId("/* id document */"), "order":{ $elemMatch:{"_id" : "/* _id in orders */" }}}, 
{$set:{"order.$.isItDone" : true}}
)
```